# Forcing trailing backslash in .htaccess causing 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find the correct `.htaccess` config to force a trailing slash after every URL, but it's causing 404's in many instances.

I have the following directory structure:-

- articles

  - post.html
- portfolio

  - lorum1.html
  - lorum2.html
  - lorum3.html
- contact.html

---

### Example 1

So if I go to:-

`myurl.com/articles/post.html` or
`myurl.com/articles/post` or 
`myurl.com/articles/post/`

I need these to all redirect to the `.html`, but with the url showing:
`myurl.com/articles/post/`

---

### Example 2

So if I go to `myurl.com/contact/`, it needs to display the content of `myurl.com/contact.html`, whilst still maintaining the `myurl.com/contact/` url.

---

### What's currently happening

Here's an example using the `contact` path. I get a 200 response if I go to `myurl.com/contact` and `myurl.com/contact.html`, but a 404 if I go to `myurl.com/contact/`.

Here's what I have so far.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Remove .html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

    # Force trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

 </IfModule>
```

I'm struggling to make sense of this problem, so thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Comment: There is a difference between a backslash (as claimed in the title) and a slash (as used in the actual question)...

Answer (score 0):

Your example is very close to hitting your requirements. The problem is that the first RewriteRule is matching `^(.*)$`, which in regex terms is equal to matching literally anything.

Your rules can be implemented by adding the missing forward slash to the regex before the end-position metacharacter `$`, meaning that the regex will now match anything, as long as it ends with a forward slash: `^(.*)/$`

Fixed:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Remove .html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html

    # Force trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

 </IfModule>
```

However while trying to understand Apache's syntax I think I found a much simpler solution to achieve the same:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite requests ending in a slash to show the html file
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html    

# If the request uri doesn't end in .html...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html?)$

# ...rewrite requests that don't end in a slash so that they do end in a slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [R=303]
```